# What changes need to be made to MVC 3 application to send e-mails?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email, actionmailer

Right now I have my MVC 3 application sending emails - but just to the C drive.

What changes need to be made in order to have the emails going to the actual addresses in the application?

Is it just a change to the Web.Config file mailSettings, which looks like this at present,

```
  <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="some-email@gmail.com">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\emailtemp\" />
    <network host="localHost" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Keep in mind this is a local copy, so I was hoping to make this change before deploying in order to test. After doing some looking around, I did see several articles mentioning a SMTP Server, I'm assuming this is only needed when going live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<specifiedPickupDirectory>` and modify your `network` node to point to your SMTP server:

```
<network host="smtp.example.com" userName="username" password="password" />
```

Comment: So I need to sign up with a smtp server ?

Comment: You can route from your own machine or any server which has SMTP setup on. Often you can use a 3rd party server such as Google's SMTP server but sometimes these require  authentication

Comment: ok, I'll give it go. and this will work even though this is a local copy of application and not the live version ?

Comment: @mkell yes it will work locally with a remote smtyp server (but watch out for firewalls/antivirus blocking outbound messages).

Comment: Cheers guys , I signed up with SocketLabs and awaiting to be verified, I will then plug the info into the network host tag.